# Akka Websocket Client to Kafka Producer

Tags: websocket, stream, apache-kafka, akka, producer

I am connecting to a websocket(stock market) and getting trades from it in the Sink and I want to publish those trades to Kafka.
I am able to send some test messages(String) to Kafka but unable to connect the actual trades to the Kafka Publisher

Here I have actorsystem, actor materializer, system dispatcher, then reactive kafka producer at 9092(port). Then I am printing trades made on console which is good. Instead of printing to console, I want to send those trades to kafka producer.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
import system.dispatcher

val kafka = new ReactiveKafka()

val producer = ReactiveKafkaProducer[Array[Byte], String](ProducerProperties(
  bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
  topic = "binance",
  valueSerializer = new StringSerializer()
))


val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(
    Sink.foreach(println),
    Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right)

// Test messages to Kafka Producer is working fine
producer.producer.send(new ProducerRecord("binance","foo"))
producer.producer.send(new ProducerRecord("binance","bar"))

val (upgradeResponse, promise) =
  Http().singleWebSocketRequest(
    WebSocketRequest("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbbtc@trade"),
    flow)
val connected = upgradeResponse.map { upgrade =>
  if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
    Done
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
  }
}
connected.onComplete(println)
```

**Trades printed on console:** 
   Success(Done)
TextMessage.Strict({"e":"trade","E":1518536267285,"s":"BNBBTC","t":9161710,"p":"0.00106130","q":"7.43000000","b":23819006,"a":23819013,"T":1518536267283,"m":true,"M":true})
TextMessage.Strict({"e":"trade","E":1518536267920,"s":"BNBBTC","t":9161711,"p":"0.00106210","q":"20.00000000","b":23819014,"a":23819010,"T":1518536267917,"m":false,"M":true})
TextMessage.Strict({"e":"trade","E":1518536272108,"s":"BNBBTC","t":9161712,"p":"0.00106150","q":"47.03000000","b":23819019,"a":23819020,"T":1518536272104,"m":true,"M":true})
TextMessage.Strict({"e":"trade","E":1518536276145,"s":"BNBBTC","t":9161713,"p":"0.00106180","q":"1.29000000","b":23819028,"a":23819027,"T":1518536276142,"m":false,"M":true})

Please also let me know how to handle the message as it is JSON and send to kafka producer

Answer (score 0):

It worked with this piece of code

```
val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(
    Sink.foreach[Message](record=>producer.producer.send(new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte],String]("binance",record.toString()))),
    Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right)
```